# How to make a sql limit

Tags: mysql, sql-server

im making a database system where i want to make a maximum limit on how many seats are avalible. For each movie there should be only 100 seats. What should i do?

```
create table customer 
(p_No int not null,
name varchar (30),
lastname varchar (30),
constraint p_No_pk primary key(p_No))

create table movie
(title varchar (500),  
movie_No int not null,
seats int check(seats < 100),
date datetime, 
primary key(movie_No))

create table ticket 
(ticket_No int identity (1,1) not null,
movie_No int not null,
p_No int not null,
primary key(ticket_No),
foreign key(movie_No)
references movie (movie_No),
foreign key(p_No) 
references customer(p_No))
```

Comment: Create the `ticket` table with 100 records, and make sure your app logic only modifies those records, but never inserts new ones.  Add a column indicating whether or not a seat be available.

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/) and [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) are different products provided by different companies. They implement and extend the standard SQL in different ways. Please tag your question with the product to use.

Answer (score 2):

create a **check contraint** as below.... **SQL SERVER**

```
create table movie
(title varchar (500),  
movie_No int not null,
seats int ,
date datetime, 
primary key(movie_No)
CONSTRAINT CHK_seats   
   CHECK (seats <100))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CHECK constraint. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (x TINYINT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (x BETWEEN 1 AND 100));
```

Or you can create an AFTER INSERT trigger on the table.

```
create trigger LimitTable
on YourTableToLimit
after insert
as
declare @tableCount int
select @tableCount = Count(*)
from YourTableToLimit

if @tableCount > 100
begin
    rollback
end
go
```

Comment: Check constraint to ensure the number of seats available for a movie is always < 100. Trigger to ensure that the number of Ticket rows created for that movie is always <= the max for that movie.